# Wordpress admin not loading css/js

Tags: wordpress

I'm having a problem with the admin on a Wordpress site. I've scoured the interwebs and seen lots of other people with the same problem, but no definite solution. The admin is showing like this:

[image]

And when I inspect it, I get a *500 (Internal Server Error)* on both *load-styles.php* and *load-scripts.php*

Anyone know what's up, and how to rectify?

Comment: Have you tried uninstailling and then reinstallining Wordpress?

Comment: are you getting the same error on your subpages, like `Add New`?

Comment: I had a similar problem, managed to fix it by hitting the Reinstall Now button on the Updates page under "If you need to re-install version 5.3.2–en_AU, you can do so here:"

Answer (score 151):

In `wp-config.php` before `require_once` add below code into file :

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

Comment: Confirmed. This one is the one that works. The other answer below kind of works too but not nearly as well as this one. Deleting browser cache and everything, that was useless. Just as another note - if you installed wordpress using digitalocean, you have to go to cd /var/www/html to find your wp-config.php file. Took me a stupid amount of time to find it.

Comment: This worked for me and worked only before "require once", I tried before using other thread here and put it under, and did not work.

Comment: Excellent soluiton.

Comment: Does the Job works even in 2022

Comment: The only thing that worked for me. Spent 4 hours trying to fix it. Nothing else worked (deleting all plugins and themes, disabling cache). Thank you!

Comment: it also worked for me before starting of 2023, thanks :)

Comment: Also worked for me WordPress on bluehost. Just pasted it above `require_once`.

Comment: Worked for me it's 29th Jan 2024 and it's still working. Thanks

Answer (score 26):

Just to keep everything in one answer, this worked for me:

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

After page refreshing and it looks OK, maybe after re-login, set SCRIPT_DEBUG to false.

Don't forget about those last two settings if you're using a plugins for debugging or site optimization - though such plugins might override those settings.

Comment: This works except using localhost leads to no valid ssl keys. And commenting out force_ssl leads to prefect working scenario.

Comment: This is work for me. Add before require_once to works like charm!!!!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Also had similar issues that affected custom fields and elementor plugins only after upgrade to the latest version of wordpress (5.5.1).
It was affected by the theme used (not developed by me). Switching between a default theme fixed the problem.
There were no errors displayed or logged.
Also project in live server without xdebug or other means of debugging except plain old way.

A simple change made, were there is no more 'type="text/css"' in the tag and the use of a pregmatch filter was the problem :)

```
preg_match_all("!<link rel='stylesheet'\s?(id='[^']+')?\s+href='(.*)' type='text/css' media='(.*)' />!", $input, $matches);
```

fix:

```
preg_match_all("!<link rel='stylesheet'\s?(id='[^']+')?\s+href='(.*)' (?:type='text\/css')*media='(.*)' \/>!", $input, $matches);
```

Found e perfect inspiration here [enter link description here](https://zerogravitymarketing.com/updating-to-wordpress-5-3-caused-admin-css-issues/).

Comment: Oh wow! I've been having this problem for such a long time and this is the only fix I've found to work for me (out of about 15 which I've tried)!! Thank you very much. In my situation, the dashboard styling was gone after updating to v5.6, despite the clone staging site working perfectly fine on 5.6... 
Either way, going into my theme's lib/cleanup.php and replacing these lines worked instantly! Can't believe it! Thanks very much :))

Answer (score 0):

the CSS was not loaded in my case ( with WordPress 3.7.1) because of an encoding problem.

Force UTF-8 encoding by replacing in `wp-admin/load-styles.php` the corresponding line by :

```
header('Content-Type: text/css; charset=UTF-8');
```

Comment: In my case this line is correct but still, WordPress is unable to load load-styles.php on Add New page only, on other pages, it is working fine. Version 5.8.1

Answer (score 0):

Put `define('SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);` in wp-config.php and debug through console. It will tell you which file is not found during page load.

Answer (score 0):

In wp-config.php file you can add - define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true);
This solves the problem but, it is not good practice to leave this config on true while on production.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar issue with a new installation of Wordpress that needed redirecting to a temporary url.

My solution was to make sure the siteurl and home url had the http:// at the beginning of the url.

Hope it fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP Memory Limit could also be the problem, if it is too low for the page loading in backend, WP simply stops loading scripts. Setting up MemoryLimit 256->512 worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

Using Lightsail with wordpress bitnami and wp-rocket here. Too specific to be honest.

The problem was the cache, wp-rocket is not compatible with mod_pagespeed.

The solution was to purge the mod_pagespeed cache

```
sudo touch <installdir>/apache2/var/cache/mod_pagespeed/cache.flush
```

Then

```
sudo <installdir>/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

And after, disable the mod, commenting out the following lines in the `<installdir>/apache2/conf/httpd.conf` file:

```
  #Include conf/pagespeed.conf
  #Include conf/pagespeed_libraries.conf
```

and restart for second time apache

```
sudo <installdir>/ctlscript.sh restart apache
```

Where `<installdir>` was `/opt/bitnami`, could change for multisite, if I'm not wrong

[Source wp-rocket incompatibility](https://docs.wp-rocket.me/article/1376-mod-pagespeed)

[Source disable mod_pagespeed](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/wordpress/administration/use-pagespeed/#disable-pagespeed)

Answer (score 0):

First check with what file does not loading (404)
Then you can identify which file does not load. If WordPress `wp-admin` or `wp-include` then check your WordPress version and replace the file. Then your issue will be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had deregistered dashicons:

```
wp_deregister_style('dashicons');
```

Removing that line made the admin-bar.css file load again.

Answer (score -3):

i know this is an old post
but maybe i can help other who are having the same issus

before you put another codes in you wp-config file , make sure that the folder wp-content permissions is 755