# Wordpress backend without css

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with my Wordpress page. While the frontend works perfectly, the backend pages (after login) miss their css files. I looked into the requests and there is a request to load_styles.php and several to load_scripts.php that all return 403. This is the request for the styles:

```
https://.../wp-admin/load-styles.php?c=0&dir=ltr&load[]=dashicons,wp-jquery-ui-dialog,admin-bar,common,forms,admin-menu,dashboard,list-tables,edit,revisions,media,themes,about,nav-menu&load[]=s,wp-pointer,widgets,site-icon,l10n,buttons,wp-auth-check,wp-color-picker&ver=5.2
```

I already checked the file permissions, but they seem to be ok (For the folders rwx,rx,rx and for the php files rw, r, r). I also deactivated all plugins. The error occured after I restored all the files in the web directory. Someone else tried to wipe everything before I was involved with the page. Any ideas?

Comment: HTTP 403 indicates that the server is refusing access to the files. What webserver are you using (Apache, IIS or other)?

Comment: It's an apache webserver

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wordpress admin not loading css/js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769141/wordpress-admin-not-loading-css-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In wp-config.php before require_once add below code into file :

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

[Wordpress admin not loading css/js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769141/wordpress-admin-not-loading-css-js)

Comment: yes by default scripts are not concatinated and it night be due to some plugin that scripts might be concatinating

Answer (score 0):

You can try to restore you database to yesterday. It seems that you plugins has errors even you disable them.

otherwize, you php code may error. this is all.

[image]