# How to fix wordpress dashboard appear in html only

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with WordPress website,, the customer added a link to the home page then the website crashed and the WordPress dashboard appear in html only.

I tried to edit the load style CSS file and edit the configuration file but nothing worked with me,, I can't post an image because I am new here,, please I need help as fast as possible,, thank you.

I tried this code 
error_reporting(0);

...and change it to this...

error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );
in the load style css file.

I have the same problem showed in this article but the solution didn't work with me.
https://manovotny.com/fix-wordpress-admin-styles-not-loading

Answer (score 0):

In `wp-config.php` before `require_once` add below code into file

```
define('FORCE_SSL_LOGIN', true);
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

Add Below line in `wp-config.php` you can show the error also.

```
define(‘WP_DEBUG’, true);
```

================================================================

Also, Try below instruction.

Try manually resetting your plugins (no Dashboard access required). If that resolves the issue, reactivate each one individually until you find the cause.

Comment: thank you ,, but it gives me a file not found error

Comment: File not found (404 error)

If you think what you're looking for should be here, please contact the site owner. The same thing :( .. thank you

Comment: Yes its appear when I try to load wp-admin page.

Answer (score 0):

In your wordpress **wp-config.php** before require_once add below code into file

```
define('CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false);
```

Comment: @Shatha share your url or screenshot

Comment: www.jamalabed.com this is the website url .. and the dashboard is just looks like the screen shot in the article in the description,, I'm sorry but because I'm new I can't post an image.

Comment: @Shatha i am not able to access your website

Comment: when I access my own website it gives me "Hmm. We’re having trouble finding that site." ,, the website crashed too ,, not just the dashboard .

Comment: @Shatha hmm how can i help without any access :)

Comment: :((( .. I told you that the main problem that the dashboard is in html and nothing works .. I can't access any page .. I really don't what exactly they  did and cause this problem :'( .. thank you so much

Comment: @Shatha i think something are missing in wordpress setup otherwise this code is working fine other people check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56211300/wordpress-backend-without-css

Comment: Ok .. I'll check it .. I hope I could solve the problem .. thank you

Comment: Hi @Shatha if this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this