# Wordpress admin panel missing styles and scripts

Tags: php, wordpress, file-permissions, http-status-code-403

My Wordpress site, which was migrated from a subfolder (think `/var/www/sitename/new_site/`) to the site root folder (`/var/www/sitename/`). I used the plugin Search & Replace to fix all missing images and styles.

However, now the admin panel won't load any styles and just displays plaintext links.
[image]

When I look at the network tab in developer tools, I see that 2 files returned HTTP 403 Forbidden - 1 request for `/wp-admin/load-styles.php` and 3 requests for `/wp-admin/load-scripts`.
[image]

I have already attempted to use

```
define( ‘CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS’, false );
define( ‘SCRIPT_DEBUG’, true );
```

This did not fix the problem.

The permissions for the `wp-admin` directories and files are `755` and `644` respectively.
I also generated a new `.htaccess` file using "Save Changes" in the Permalinks settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Wordpress admin not loading css/js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18769141/wordpress-admin-not-loading-css-js)

Comment: @Laim As I mentioned in my post, I already tried the methods mentioned in your link. They did not help. The site also has a valid certificate, so SSL shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: The quotes in your define statements aren't valid. Use either `'` or `"`. Have you checked the server's error logs?

Comment: @j08691 Oh my god you're right! I copied the statements from the linked answer. How did I not notice that? How do I give you credit? Can you put this as an answer?

Comment: @j08691 Also, I couldn't check the logs, because I only have `read` access to the site root directory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are the correct statements:

```
define( 'CONCATENATE_SCRIPTS', false );
define( 'SCRIPT_DEBUG', true );
```

The code I copied had incorrect quotation marks. Thanks goes to @j08691 for pointing this out.